# removing a URL from browser history through javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-appcache

We are moving our website from http to https. When you go to the address bar and start typing "my_s..." the browser suggests "http://my_site.com". I've got it set up to redirect, but I'd rather not have the user go through that step. Is there any way to get the browser to forget "http://my_site.com" or get it to prefer "https://my_site.com"?

A complication is that I'm using appcache because we are supporting offline mode, and we have some automatic ajax calls that happen in the background, too.

Comment: As far as I know there is none. Set up a .htaccess redirect so your clients browse your https version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This saved data is handled by the browser.  You'll have to have the users delete the browser history, or set up redirects for http to https

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was having issues setting up the redirect if the user has the old site in appcache. They won't even go to the server to see the redirect. So my solution so far is to put the redirect in the browser, so they will download the new version on http:, then it will redirect. It works, but it isn't very seamless. And I doubt I'll have much luck in getting the users to delete their browser history.